# Discrepency with Jenkins Crumb value

Tags: jenkins, postman

I am using Postman API to create new job in Jenkins.Inside Postman UI,with GET request the Jenkins-crumb I am getting gives me proper output i.e.Status 200 Ok when passed into POST request.
But when I am hitting same URL(used in GET request) outside Postman UI, the crumb value that I get gives me "*403 NO valid crumb included in request*".

How we can solve this issue?

Comment: You might want to share how you set up the request in postman and then how you do it outside of postman. It's hard to tell from your pure description what goes wrong.

Comment: Inside Postman:  I have a url in GET request which returns jenkins-crumb value.When jenkins-crumb value is passed in POST method,I receive status:200 OK.                        Outside Postman : Url in GET method passed in google chrome returns jenkins-crumb value, When jenkins-crumb value is passed in POST method inside POSTMAN, I receive status: "403 NO valid crumb included in request"               URL in GET-Http://HOSTNAME:PORT/crumbIssuer/api/json                                        URL in POST-Http://HOSTNAME:PORT/createItem?name=

Comment: You should include these details in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly its due to the security constraints in Jenkins https://jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.176/

To fix, you might use options specified in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59261140/374133

I had same issue while  using  C#, and it got solved by using the same HttpClient for requesting crumb and triggering build. Got the idea from this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103522/374133