# Jenkins giving 403 in EC2 Server after passing the crumb in the request headers

Tags: java, jenkins, java-8

i am using the CSRF Jenkins crumbs in the API call to create a new job in Jenkins from Java.

I tried the following

Called the API to get the crumb data

> http://admin:11542c80972c3a2b863453d234de68b1d@10.139.163.33/crumbIssuer/api/json

I also tried with the below URL

> http://10.139.163.33/crumbIssuer/api/json

The below is the JSON response obtained from the server

{"_class":"hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer","crumb":"b272a09b604e7b7cc8ee1431f0a0143fa1422db2fb5f92955b0356a31da37463","crumbRequestField":"Jenkins-Crumb"}

In the next step, I am making a call to the Jenkins to create a new job with the header as

```
Jenkins-Crumb:b272a09b604e7b7cc8ee1431f0a0143fa1422db2fb5f92955b0356a31da37463
```

Jenkins is giving me 403, I am using HttpGet to get the token and using HttpPost with the header as above and sending to jenkins.

When i try with postman, it is not giving this error. I am running the Java application in 1 ec2 server and jenkins on another ec2 server.

There are no proxies, I also tried to use the various options like the enable proxy compatibilty, restarting jenkins etc, but not working.

Please give any pointers.

Java code used is

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
    JenkinsCrumb crumb = jenkinsHelper.getCrumb();
    String encodedPassword = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((user + ":" + pwd).getBytes());
    postRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encodedPassword);
    postRequest.addHeader(new BasicHeader(crumb.getCrumbRequestField(), crumb.getCrumb()));
    return postRequest;
```

The code to get the crumb is

```
String urlWithToken = "http://" + (user + ":" + pwd) + "@";
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(jenkinsBaseUrl.replace("http://", urlWithToken) + "crumbIssuer/api/json");
                request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encodedPassword);
                CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
```

I have also tried with the CURL command and still getting the same response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using the same HttpClient (CloseableHttpClient) for both the CRUMB and the POST Request. Earlier, I was using 2 separate clients one for getting the crumb and new one for the posting of the data. Using a shared httpclient for both of these resulted in success state.

Hope this helps any other developer facing similar issue.